# POST Python 3 requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

In the Chrome developer console, it is possible to POST a request like:

```js
$.post( "add_to_offer_ajax.php", { No: 'SZ412042400Q', Quantity: '1' })
```

This works fine and adds an item to an online quote.

How can I convert this POST to Python 3 and requests? I tried the following, but this does not seem to work:

```
response =requests.post("https://webshop.seaco.eu/add_to_offer_ajax.php", data={"No": 'SZ412042400Q',"Quantity": "1"})
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my post, learning from this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json` parameter instead:

```
response = requests.post("https://webshop.seaco.eu/add_to_offer_ajax.php", json={"No": 'SZ412042400Q',"Quantity": "1"})
```

Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for details.